# Short Interface implementation in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, interface-segregation-principle

### Now

in kotlin we have a possibility to implement the interface like this:

```
interface AnimalStrategy {
fun eat(): Outcome
}
```

### Want to have

***Question***: Is it possible to declare the interface in kotlin in shorter syntax?

```
interface AnimalStrategy = fun eat(): Outcome
```

Comment: There is no such syntax. You can use `typealias` to a function. but that loses the function name that you want to override. `typealias AnimalStrategy = ()-> Outcome`

Comment: Btw why do you have `interface-segregation-principle` as the tag? What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the use case for this?  The benefit seems minimal (replacing two braces with one equals sign) and the usage very restricted (it could only apply to interfaces with a single function, having no documentation).  And for those cases, maybe a function type might be a better choice?

Comment: thx for the replies.
i am implementing a strategy pattern. Classes which implement a specific strategy should override the defined method.

In my example a Cat class should implement the interface AnimalStrategy and override the single function eat().

Comment: Do you realize you can simply type your first code as one line? Your suggested syntax only saves two characters, and adds an overload to the meaning of `=`.